# Yeoman angular is not proceeding... stuck at a point

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

Hi folks below is the output of terminal while creating yo angular

```
sudo yo angular
[sudo] password for sh4rif: 

     _-----_
    |       |    .--------------------------.
    |--(o)--|    |    Welcome to Yeoman,    |
   `---------´   |   ladies and gentlemen!  |
    ( _´U`_ )    '--------------------------'
    /___A___\    
     |  ~  |     
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

Out of the box I include Bootstrap and some AngularJS recommended modules.

? Would you like to use Sass (with Compass)? No
? Would you like to include Bootstrap? Yes
? Which modules would you like to include? angular-animate.js, angular-cookies.js, angular-resource.js, angular-route.js, angular-sanitize.js, angular-touch.js
   create app/styles/main.css
   create app/index.html
   create bower.json
identical .bowerrc
   create package.json
   create Gruntfile.js
   invoke   angular:common:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
identical     .editorconfig
identical     .gitattributes
identical     .jshintrc
identical     .gitignore
   create     test/.jshintrc
   create     app/.buildignore
   create     app/.htaccess
   create     app/404.html
   create     app/favicon.ico
   create     app/robots.txt
   create     app/views/main.html
   create     app/images/yeoman.png
   invoke   angular:main:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
   create     app/scripts/app.js
   invoke   angular:controller:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
   create     app/scripts/controllers/main.js
   create     test/spec/controllers/main.js
   invoke   karma:app


I'm all done. Running bower install & npm install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.


   invoke       angular:route
   invoke           angular:controller:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/route/index.js
   create             app/scripts/controllers/about.js
   create             test/spec/controllers/about.js
   invoke           angular:view:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/route/index.js
   create             app/views/about.html
   create     test/karma.conf.js
identical     .travis.yml
npm WARN package.json firstapp@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json firstapp@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json firstapp@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json firstapp@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json firstapp@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json firstapp@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN deprecated grunt-ngmin@0.0.3: use grunt-ng-annotate insteadover time? (Y/n) -
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma@>=0.9 included from karma-phantomjs-launcher will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma@>=0.9 included from karma-jasmine will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency jasmine-core@* included from karma-jasmine will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency grunt@0.4.x included from grunt-karma will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma@~0.12.0 included from grunt-karma will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN engine karma@0.12.31: wanted: {"node":"~0.8 || ~0.10"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN deprecated ngmin@0.4.1: use ng-annotate instead
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.5

> phantomjs@1.9.16 install /home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

Download already available at /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
Removing /home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1428162762160/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64 -> /home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs

> ws@0.4.32 install /home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node: Finished
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory `/home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/bower requires chalk@'^1.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/chalk,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/google-cdn/node_modules/bower requires chalk@'0.5.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/chalk,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/google-cdn/node_modules/cdnjs-cdn-data requires semver@'~2.2.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/google-cdn/node_modules/semver,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.3.2
grunt-karma@0.10.1 node_modules/grunt-karma
└── lodash@2.4.1

karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher
└── phantomjs@1.9.16 (which@1.0.9, progress@1.1.8, kew@0.4.0, adm-zip@0.4.4, request-progress@0.3.1, npmconf@2.1.1, request@2.42.0, fs-extra@0.16.5)

jasmine-core@2.2.0 node_modules/jasmine-core

karma@0.12.31 node_modules/karma
├── di@0.0.1
├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── mime@1.2.11
├── q@0.9.7
├── source-map@0.1.43 (amdefine@0.1.0)
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── lodash@2.4.1
├── useragent@2.0.10 (lru-cache@2.2.4)
├── log4js@0.6.22 (semver@1.1.4, async@0.2.10, readable-stream@1.0.33)
├── chokidar@0.12.6 (async-each@0.1.6, readdirp@1.3.0)
├── http-proxy@0.10.4 (pkginfo@0.3.0, utile@0.2.1)
├── connect@2.26.6 (fresh@0.2.4, cookie@0.1.2, pause@0.0.1, cookie-signature@1.0.5, response-time@2.0.1, vhost@3.0.0, basic-auth-connect@1.0.0, on-headers@1.0.0, bytes@1.0.0, media-typer@0.3.0, parseurl@1.3.0, depd@0.4.5, connect-timeout@1.3.0, cookie-parser@1.3.4, qs@2.2.4, debug@2.0.0, finalhandler@0.2.0, method-override@2.2.0, serve-favicon@2.1.7, type-is@1.5.7, multiparty@3.3.2, morgan@1.3.2, body-parser@1.8.4, csurf@1.6.6, serve-static@1.6.5, errorhandler@1.2.4, compression@1.1.2, serve-index@1.2.1, express-session@1.8.2)
└── socket.io@0.9.16 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-client@0.9.16)

karma-jasmine@0.3.5 node_modules/karma-jasmine

> pngquant-bin@0.3.5 postinstall /home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-pngquant/node_modules/pngquant-bin
> node index.js

✔ pre-build test passed successfully!

> gifsicle@0.1.7 postinstall /home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-gifsicle/node_modules/gifsicle
> node index.js

✔ pre-build test passed successfully!

> optipng-bin@0.3.11 postinstall /home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-optipng/node_modules/optipng-bin
> node index.js

✔ pre-build test passed successfully!

> jpegtran-bin@0.2.8 postinstall /home/sh4rif/Documents/yeoman/firstapp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-jpegtran/node_modules/jpegtran-bin
> node index.js

✔ pre-build test passed successfully!
grunt-contrib-copy@0.5.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy

grunt-contrib-concat@0.4.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat
└── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)

jshint-stylish@0.2.0 node_modules/jshint-stylish
├── text-table@0.2.0
└── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)

grunt-filerev@0.2.1 node_modules/grunt-filerev
├── each-async@0.1.3
└── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)

time-grunt@0.3.2 node_modules/time-grunt
├── date-time@0.1.1
├── pretty-ms@0.1.0
├── text-table@0.2.0
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
└── hooker@0.2.3

grunt-concurrent@0.5.0 node_modules/grunt-concurrent
├── pad-stdio@0.1.1 (lpad@0.2.1)
└── async@0.2.10

grunt-contrib-clean@0.5.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean
└── rimraf@2.2.8

grunt-newer@0.7.0 node_modules/grunt-newer
├── rimraf@2.2.6
└── async@0.2.10

grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.9.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
├── clean-css@2.1.8 (commander@2.1.0)
└── maxmin@0.1.0 (pretty-bytes@0.1.2, gzip-size@0.1.1)

grunt-contrib-watch@0.6.1 node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch
├── async@0.2.10
├── tiny-lr-fork@0.0.5 (debug@0.7.4, faye-websocket@0.4.4, noptify@0.0.3, qs@0.5.6)
├── gaze@0.5.1 (globule@0.1.0)
└── lodash@2.4.1

grunt-usemin@2.6.2 node_modules/grunt-usemin
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@0.2.0, has-ansi@0.1.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0)
├── debug@2.1.3 (ms@0.7.0)
└── lodash@2.4.1

load-grunt-tasks@0.4.0 node_modules/load-grunt-tasks
├── multimatch@0.1.0 (minimatch@0.2.14, lodash@2.4.1)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (glob@3.2.11, lodash@2.4.1)

grunt-contrib-uglify@0.4.1 node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
├── maxmin@0.1.0 (pretty-bytes@0.1.2, gzip-size@0.1.1)
└── uglify-js@2.4.19 (uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2, async@0.2.10, yargs@3.5.4, source-map@0.1.34)

grunt-ngmin@0.0.3 node_modules/grunt-ngmin
└── ngmin@0.4.1 (astral@0.1.0, clone@0.1.19, commander@1.1.1, astral-angular-annotate@0.0.2, esprima@1.0.4, escodegen@0.0.28)

grunt-contrib-htmlmin@0.3.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-htmlmin
├── pretty-bytes@0.1.2
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
└── html-minifier@0.6.9 (relateurl@0.2.6, change-case@2.1.6, clean-css@2.2.23, cli@0.6.6, uglify-js@2.4.19)

grunt@0.4.5 node_modules/grunt
├── which@1.0.9
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── eventemitter2@0.4.14
├── getobject@0.1.0
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── async@0.1.22
├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── exit@0.1.2
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.0, graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── lodash@0.9.2
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── underscore.string@2.2.1
├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
├── findup-sync@0.1.3 (glob@3.2.11, lodash@2.4.1)
├── grunt-legacy-log@0.1.1 (underscore.string@2.3.3, lodash@2.4.1)
└── js-yaml@2.0.5 (argparse@0.1.16, esprima@1.0.4)

grunt-svgmin@0.4.0 node_modules/grunt-svgmin
├── each-async@0.1.3
├── pretty-bytes@0.1.2
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
└── svgo@0.4.5 (colors@0.6.2, whet.extend@0.9.9, coa@0.4.1, sax@0.6.1, js-yaml@2.1.3)

grunt-wiredep@1.9.0 node_modules/grunt-wiredep
└── wiredep@1.8.6 (propprop@0.3.0, minimist@1.1.1, chalk@0.5.1, through2@0.6.3, glob@4.5.3, lodash@2.4.1, bower-config@0.5.2)

grunt-contrib-jshint@0.10.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint
├── hooker@0.2.3
└── jshint@2.5.11 (strip-json-comments@1.0.2, underscore@1.6.0, exit@0.1.2, console-browserify@1.1.0, shelljs@0.3.0, minimatch@1.0.0, cli@0.6.6, htmlparser2@3.8.2)

grunt-autoprefixer@0.7.6 node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer
├── diff@1.0.8
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
└── autoprefixer@1.3.1 (fs-extra@0.9.1, postcss@0.3.5, caniuse-db@1.0.30000114)

grunt-google-cdn@0.4.3 node_modules/grunt-google-cdn
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@0.2.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)
├── bower@1.4.1 (is-root@1.0.0, junk@1.0.1, stringify-object@1.0.1, user-home@1.1.1, which@1.0.9, abbrev@1.0.5, chmodr@0.1.0, rimraf@2.3.2, archy@1.0.0, opn@1.0.1, bower-logger@0.2.2, lru-cache@2.5.0, bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.2, graceful-fs@3.0.6, lockfile@1.0.0, nopt@3.0.1, retry@0.6.1, tmp@0.0.24, q@1.2.0, request-progress@0.3.1, chalk@1.0.0, shell-quote@1.4.3, bower-json@0.4.0, semver@2.3.2, promptly@0.2.0, p-throttler@0.1.1, fstream@1.0.4, mkdirp@0.5.0, tar-fs@1.5.0, fstream-ignore@1.0.2, glob@4.5.3, insight@0.5.3, update-notifier@0.3.1, decompress-zip@0.1.0, github@0.2.3, request@2.53.0, bower-registry-client@0.3.0, cardinal@0.4.4, mout@0.11.0, bower-config@0.6.1, configstore@0.3.2, inquirer@0.8.0, handlebars@2.0.0)
└── google-cdn@0.7.0 (regexp-quote@0.0.0, google-cdn-data@0.1.17, debug@1.0.4, async@0.9.0, semver@2.3.2, cdnjs-cdn-data@0.1.1, bower@1.3.12)

grunt-contrib-connect@0.7.1 node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect
├── connect-livereload@0.3.2
├── open@0.0.4
├── async@0.2.10
├── portscanner@0.2.2 (async@0.1.15)
└── connect@2.13.1 (uid2@0.0.3, methods@0.1.0, cookie-signature@1.0.1, pause@0.0.1, debug@0.8.1, fresh@0.2.0, qs@0.6.6, bytes@0.2.1, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, raw-body@1.1.3, batch@0.5.0, cookie@0.1.0, compressible@1.0.0, negotiator@0.3.0, send@0.1.4, multiparty@2.2.0)

grunt-contrib-imagemin@0.7.2 node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin
├── pretty-bytes@0.1.2
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
├── async@0.7.0
└── imagemin@0.4.9 (stat-mode@0.2.0, ware@0.3.0, nopt@3.0.1, image-type@0.1.4, tempfile@0.1.3, fs-extra@0.10.0, rimraf@2.3.2, imagemin-svgo@0.1.1, imagemin-pngquant@0.1.3, imagemin-gifsicle@0.1.1, imagemin-optipng@0.1.0, imagemin-jpegtran@0.1.0)
```

I've trid this three four time deleted and re run the command but every time i run this it come at and stop at this point (look at the very last line of the output) and if I press `ctrl+c` to quite and restart i get the following errors... The following lines are after when I pressed `ctrl+c`

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:89
  if ($._.isString(componentConfigFile.main)) {
                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined
    at findMainFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:89:39)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:151:17
    at forOwn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:2105:15)
    at Function.forEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:3302:9)
    at detectDependencies (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:33:7)
    at wiredep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/wiredep.js:65:39)
    at Generator._injectDependencies (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js:326:5)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:232:13
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:119:25
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:24:1
```

version numbers of `node yo and npm`

```
node --version && yo --version && npm --version
v0.12.2
1.4.6
2.7.4
```

Don't know what should I do, any idea?

Comment: Could you list your node and npm versions? Also it's not a great idea to use sudo when running a generator. Generators are just structuring a project and should only install dependencies locally.

Comment: @gjeck I've added the version numbers of `node`, `yo` and `npm`

Comment: Looks like the Karma dependency might be causing problems. Try npm uninstall-g karma then in your package.json set a specific version for karma (try their latest release)

Comment: I know it's been long, but has anyone found an answer to this? I am having the same problem here too.